# Can we write message to different response object in java web app?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts

I'm trying to send message to online user by user's servlet response object which is already stored in map. For Example if user A is to send message to B then i will get data from A's request object and write it to B's response object(from map).  I'm trying it for avoid timed ajax call. Any suggestion and help. I'm getting message when reload the jsp page.can we have object listener in jsp.

Answer (score 1):

*IMHO*,The `servlet response` will be sent back to the client when the `doGet or Post` method terminates, it won't wait for your `asynchronous call`(time that getting data from A's ) to finish.

You may face the issue `"response alredy has been committed"`

Comment: No, i'm getting message when refresh the page.

Comment: Yup,when you refresh the page,control goes in to doget so you are getting that in response.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: The link @Baadshah sent is good if you want B to get the message without having to refresh the page. Still, not sure why you would want to use that instead of Ajax or just doing periodic refresh on B's page

Comment: @daramasala yeah.Me too did'nt get the reason behind avoid ajax.

Answer (score 0):

*if user A is to send message to B then i will get data from A's request object and write it to B's response object(from map).*

The request object of A and the response object of B, will be in different threads running the Servlet's `service()` method .I think you need to store the data sent using A's request in some app context probably and push it to B using AJAX or when user B makes a request fetch the data from context and send it to response to B.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this - don't mix requests and responses from different servlet calls.
Either use Ajax or periodic refresh using javascript or something similar.
You can use Comet (server push) but really Ajax or refresh are natural for your use case.
(Unless you have other concerns which you didn't share)